# Painting over JMF component

Tags: java, swing, jmf, augmented-reality

I'm capturing the Stream from a webcam and would like to draw something on top of the video image. I try that in the example below, the problem is that the other component is always in the background no matter how I arrange the components.
Is there a way do solve this?

```
public class SwingCapture extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1284686239737730338L;
private static Player player = null;
public static final int WIDTH = 640;
public static final int HEIGHT = 480;
private MediaLocator ml = null;

public SwingCapture() 
{
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    ml = new MediaLocator("vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0"); 
    try  {
        player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(ml);
        player.start();

        Component comp = null;
        if ((comp = player.getVisualComponent()) != null) {
            add(comp);   
            comp.setBounds(0, 0, 640, 480);
        }
        add(Canvas.getInstance());
        Canvas.getInstance().setBounds(0, 0, 640, 480);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void playerclose() {
   player.close();
   player.deallocate();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I used a Manager.setHint(Manager.LIGHTWEIGHT_RENDERER, true);
 and a JLayerPane.

```
public class SwingCapture extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1284686239737730338L;
public static Player player = null;
public static final int WIDTH = 640;
public static final int HEIGHT = 480;
public MediaLocator ml = null;

public SwingCapture() {
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    JLayeredPane jLP = new JLayeredPane(); 
    jLP.setBounds(0,0,800,600);
    ml = new MediaLocator("vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0"); 
    try  {
        Manager.setHint(Manager.LIGHTWEIGHT_RENDERER, true);
        player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(ml);
        player.start();
        jLP.add(Canvas.getInstance());
        Canvas.getInstance().setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
        Component comp = null;
        if ((comp = player.getVisualComponent()) != null) {
            jLP.add(comp, -1);   
            comp.setBounds(0, 0, 640, 480);
        }

        add(jLP);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 public static void playerclose() 
 {
    player.close();
    player.deallocate();
 }
}
```