# FMJ Webcam capture example

Tags: java, webcam, capture, fmj

I've been searching for while now and I can't find a simple example of how to capture a webcam stream with FMJ. Are there any tutorials or examples available which could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been working with FMJ for a while and I haven't found many examples to start with either. What I would do is to explore the FmjStudio class that has the webcam functionality integrated and its pretty straight forward.

For bob:

What you want is FMJ. FMJ uses an DataSource implementation for civil to use it with JMF. I would recommend you to go to http://fmj-sf.net/ download the latest source and explore FmjStudio aswell since it uses civil to capture.

For theDude:

You are right, you can use JMF aswell but the same code you use for JMF will most likely work with FMJ (maybe with a coupla changes) and the performance will be much better, specially if you want a wide range of different webcams to work with your software.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't what you want to hear, but I've used JMF for this task and it works very well. There are enough examples online to get a simple web cam capture app running pretty easily. I'll post more if you're interested.

Comment: I have a JMF example with the following problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272018/painting-over-jmf-component
Thats why I wanted to try FMJ

Comment: I know this is old, but could you point me to a working JMF example?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585917/capture-live-video-from-webcam-using-java-an-jmf

Answer (score 0):

The following code would get you started.

```
GlobalCaptureDevicePlugger.addCaptureDevices(); 
    Vector<CaptureDeviceInfo> audioCapDevList = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(null);
    if (audioCapDevList.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < audioCapDevList.size(); i++) {
            audioCapDevInfo = audioCapDevList.elementAt(i);
            Format[] videoFormats = audioCapDevInfo.getFormats();
            System.out.println(audioCapDevInfo);
            if (audioCapDevInfo.getName().startsWith("vfw:")) { // assume the name of the webcam starts with vfw:
                for (int j = 0; j < videoFormats.length; j++) {
                    if (videoFormats[j] instanceof VideoFormat) {
                        currentFormat = (VideoFormat) videoFormats[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(currentFormat);
                if (currentFormat == null) {
                    System.err.println("Search for VideoFormat failed");
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
                audioCapDevLoc = audioCapDevInfo.getLocator();
            }

        }
    }
```

Please make sure the native libraries (civil.dll and jdshow.dll) are loaded into the JVM. Otherwise, you would get an java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError. The following code may do the job for you.

```
    System.setProperty("java.library.path", "D:/fmj-sf/native/win32-x86/");
    Field fieldSysPath;
    try {
        fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
        fieldSysPath.setAccessible(true);
        fieldSysPath.set(null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```